# AsyncListenableTaskExecutor in Spring and CompletableFuture in Java

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous, java-8

I was trying to use AsyncListenableTaskExecutor

Configuration

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setThreadFactory(new customizableThreadFactory("scheduled-task-"));
    executor.setCorePoolSize(8);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(8);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(4000);
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());

    return executor;
}

@Bean(name = "requestContextAwareTaskExecutor")
AsyncListenableTaskExecutor requestContextAwareTaskExecutor() {
    return new RequestContextAwareTaskExecutor(taskExecutor(), requestContextHolder);
}
```

In main Class

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ListenableFuture<String> f = 
    executor.submitListenable(getTask(i));   

    f.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<String> {
    @Override
    public void onFailure (Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("faliure message: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess (String result) {
        System.out.println("success object: " + result);
    }
    });
    }
```

Here this code works asynchronously,

If I need to collect all results to a list from here

```
@Override
public void onSuccess (String result) {
    System.out.println("success object: " + result);
}
```

I won't able to return List, won't wait for all the threads to complete before that thread returns.

So I thought of using completable future, not sure how can I use completable future in this scenario.